# My Neural Network is not able to predict XOR problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm coding a `neural_network` python module from scratch, and it seemed to be good. But, when I tested the network to predict the XOR problem, predictions were all around 0.5. I tried to change different things, from the learning rate to the number of epochs, but still the same predictions. I'm really going crazy trying to figure out what I did wrong.

These are the predictions of the NN after training

```
[0, 0] -> [[0.51725719]]
[0, 1] -> [[0.5172791]]
[1, 0] -> [[0.51720819]]
[1, 1] -> [[0.51723017]]
```

[Cost over epochs graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSC6y.png)

This is the test.py file in my repo

```
from neural_network import layers, model
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Testing my neural_network module with XOR problem

# inputs
x = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]

# labels
y = [0, 1, 1, 0]

model = model.Model(loss="mean_squared_error")
model.add(layers.Dense(2, input_shape=2, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.train(x, y, learning_rate=0.01, epochs=10000, verbose=1)

for x_test in x:
    print(x_test, model.predict(x_test))
```

For my `neural_network` module (pretty simple code) here is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/Korazza/neural_network

Comment: try a lower learn rate, like 0.001 or lower, see if that makes any changes. Also, use binary cross entropy

Comment: Try using drop out?

Comment: We have abandoned `sigmoid` activations in the intermediate layers since ages now...

Comment: @desertnaut while that is true, the ground truth XOR function is well within the range of this particular neural network architecture and shouldn't be hard for it to learn

Comment: Well, I implemented binary cross entropy and tried a lower learn rate, but it's still the same prediction output. Maybe something is wrong in my Model class, but for what I know it should be correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts, I figured out what the problem was.

My weight initialization was not the best, weights were too low.

So I implemented the `He-at-al Initialization` which provides better weight values based on the number of neurons of the current layer, and the previous one.

Here is the output for XOR problem after implementing `He-at-al Initialization`

```
[0, 0] [[0.01937993]]
[0, 1] [[0.99732982]]
[1, 0] [[0.97613504]]
[1, 1] [[0.01860087]]
```